# Load IDPs from a database Spring SAML

Tags: spring-saml

I have a Spring SAML project using java configurations where I am loading IDP metadata in from a file using a `FilesystemMetadataProvider`.  I would like to be able to load IDPs from a database on start up.  If I need to change the configuration, I don't want to have to restart the app to load in the changes.  There is a reloading `HTTPMetadataProvider`, is there one for databases? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an implementation of the [AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/org/opensaml/saml2/metadata/provider/AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.html) that does what you're looking for natively, however, it's not difficult to implement your own.

The SSOProfile contains the XML of the IDP.  The `AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider` will use the overridden methods to periodically go to the database and reload any changes to the metadata.

```
public class DatabaseMetadataProvider extends AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseMetadataProvider.class);

    private SSOProfileService samlService;

    private String entityId;

    public DatabaseMetadataProvider(Timer backgroundTaskTimer, String entityId, SSOProfileService samlService) throws MetadataProviderException {
        super(backgroundTaskTimer);
        if (entityId == null) {
            throw new MetadataProviderException("EntityId may not be null");
        }
        this.entityId = entityId;
        if (samlService == null) {
            throw new MetadataProviderException("Saml Service must not be null");
        }
        this.samlService = samlService;

    }

    @Override
    protected String getMetadataIdentifier() {
        return entityId;
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] fetchMetadata() throws MetadataProviderException {
        SSOProfile ssoSaml = samlService.getSSOSamlProfileByEntityID(entityId);
        if (ssoSaml == null) {
            log.error("Could not find a valid entity in the DB for " + entityId + " to refresh from. ");
            return null;
        } else {
            log.trace("Found idp metadata for " + ssoSaml.getEntityID() + ": " + ssoSaml.getIdpMetaData());
            return ssoSaml.getIdpMetaData().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public synchronized void destroy() {
        samlService = null;
        entityId = null;
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

The next thing you will need is a service that on start up can return a list of these MetadataProviders and load them in to your MetadataManager.